# zig externs when using zig test for wasm

Tags: zig

I have a Zig codebase that I'm compiling to WebAssembly with a build.zig like this:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
  const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();
  const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("main", "src/main.zig", b.version(0, 0, 0));
  lib.setBuildMode(mode);
  lib.setTarget(.{.cpu_arch = .wasm32, .os_tag = .freestanding});
  lib.setOutputDir("web/dist");
  b.default_step.dependOn(&lib.step);
}
```

Inside `src/main.zig` there's an `extern` that marks a function provided through the WebAssembly imports.

```
extern fn printString(message: [*]u8, length: usize) void;
```

This works fine when running in the browser, but I'm trying to add tests to the project, but whenever I attempt to run `zig test` on `main.zig` (or any file with `extern`) I get the following linker error.

```
MachO Flush... error(link): undefined reference to symbol '_printString'
```

It might be worth pointing out that nothing in my `test "..." {}` blocks actually touches any of these `extern` functions.

Is there a sane way to link to alternate implementations of these externs during tests? Or any other workarounds that would allow me to write tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combine [`@import("builtin").is_test`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.0/#Detecting-Test-Build) and `usingnamespace` to create stubs for extern functions during tests.

```
const builtin = @import("builtin");

pub usingnamespace if (!builtin.is_test) struct {
  pub extern fn printString(message: [*]u8, length: usize) void;
} else struct {
  pub fn printString(message: [*]u8, length: usize) void {
    _ = message;
    _ = length;
  }
}
```

`pub usingnamespace` makes all the members of the struct part of the module's public struct, and during tests we just use a different struct that doesn't rely on any external functions.

Credit to [mitchellh/zig-js](https://github.com/mitchellh/zig-js/blob/52eed4daddcf9fa974ad4457691de26ef2351c56/src/extern.zig#L8).